# Calculate percentage share of values against a value which is a row observation in the data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, percentage

I want to calculate the percentage share and create new columns using mutate. I have the following data:

```
country, metric, segment, value1990, value2000, value2010
canada, abc, rural, 10, 15, 16
canada, abc, urban, 12, 12, 18
canada, abc, total, 22, 27, 34
canada, xyz, rural, 6, 9, 10
canada, xyc, urban, 7, 8, 8
canada, xyc, total, 13, 17, 18
canada, population, rural, 80, 86, 95
canada, population, urban, 102, 110, 121
canada, population, total, 182, 196, 216
```

The data frame consists data from several countries and across several years. I want to create a new column with the following values

```
country, metric, segment, value, percent1990, percent2000, percent2010

canada, abc, rural, 10, 15, 16, 12.5%, 17.4%, 16.8%
canada, abc, urban, 12, 12, 18, 11.7%, 10.9%, 14.8%
canada, abc, total, 22, 27, 34, 12.1%, 13.7%, 15.7%
canada, xyz, rural, 6, 9, 10, 7.5%, 10.4%, 10.5%
canada, xyc, urban, 7, 8, 8, 6.8%, 7.2%, 6.6%
canada, xyc, total, 13, 17, 18, 7.22%, 8.6%, 8.3%
canada, population, rural, 80, 86, 95, 100%, 100%, 100%
canada, population, urban, 102, 110, 121, 100%, 100%, 100%
canada, population, total, 182, 196, 216, 100%, 100%, 100%
```

Essentially, I want to calculate the value variable's percentage share of the population depending on whether it is rural/urban/total, across multiple years.

E.g.
(row 1) `percent_share = (10/80)*100 = 12.5%`

(row 2) `percent_share = (10/102)*100 = 11.76%`

(row 3) `percent_share = (10/182)*100 = 12.09%`

I'm unable to go beyond the `group_by` chaining to ascertain how to input the necessary function

```
df = df %>%
     group_by (country, metric) %>%
     mutate(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: for new question data containing years**

This would be easier if you moved the years and the total population to new columns. Here's one way to do that.

Assuming your example data is in a data frame named `df1`: first `gather` the years.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- df1 %>% gather(Year, Value, 4:6)
```

Then filter for `metric` == `population` and join back to the original data.

```
df1 %>% filter(metric == "population") %>% 
  left_join(filter(df1, metric != "population"), 
            by = c("country", "segment", "Year")) %>% 
  select(country, segment, Year, population = Value.x, metric = metric.y, value = Value.y)
```

Result:

```
   country segment      Year population metric value
1   canada   rural value1990         80    abc    10
2   canada   rural value1990         80    xyz     6
3   canada   urban value1990        102    abc    12
4   canada   urban value1990        102    xyc     7
5   canada   total value1990        182    abc    22
6   canada   total value1990        182    xyc    13
7   canada   rural value2000         86    abc    15
8   canada   rural value2000         86    xyz     9
9   canada   urban value2000        110    abc    12
10  canada   urban value2000        110    xyc     8
11  canada   total value2000        196    abc    27
12  canada   total value2000        196    xyc    17
13  canada   rural value2010         95    abc    16
14  canada   rural value2010         95    xyz    10
15  canada   urban value2010        121    abc    18
16  canada   urban value2010        121    xyc     8
17  canada   total value2010        216    abc    34
18  canada   total value2010        216    xyc    18
```

Then add a mutate:

```
df1 %>% filter(metric == "population") %>% 
  left_join(filter(df1, metric != "population"), 
            by = c("country", "segment", "Year")) %>% 
  select(country, segment, Year, population = Value.x, metric = metric.y, value = Value.y) %>% 
  mutate(percent_share = 100 * (value / population))
```

Result:

```
   country segment      Year population metric value percent_share
1   canada   rural value1990         80    abc    10     12.500000
2   canada   rural value1990         80    xyz     6      7.500000
3   canada   urban value1990        102    abc    12     11.764706
4   canada   urban value1990        102    xyc     7      6.862745
5   canada   total value1990        182    abc    22     12.087912
6   canada   total value1990        182    xyc    13      7.142857
7   canada   rural value2000         86    abc    15     17.441860
8   canada   rural value2000         86    xyz     9     10.465116
9   canada   urban value2000        110    abc    12     10.909091
10  canada   urban value2000        110    xyc     8      7.272727
11  canada   total value2000        196    abc    27     13.775510
12  canada   total value2000        196    xyc    17      8.673469
13  canada   rural value2010         95    abc    16     16.842105
14  canada   rural value2010         95    xyz    10     10.526316
15  canada   urban value2010        121    abc    18     14.876033
16  canada   urban value2010        121    xyc     8      6.611570
17  canada   total value2010        216    abc    34     15.740741
18  canada   total value2010        216    xyc    18      8.333333
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I thought of doing the same, but dropped it cause I have the values for multiple years (in hindsight I should've mentioned this in my question). Best, R

Comment: We can try again if you care to edit the question with better example data.

Comment: Just updated the question. Appreciate your help on this!

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

You can also just group by `segment` and divide by `max(value`), since the population value should be the largest:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(country, segment) %>% 
  mutate(percent_share = value / max(value))

# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   segment [3]
  country metric     segment value percent_share
  <chr>   <chr>      <chr>   <dbl>         <dbl>
1 canada  abc        rural      10        0.125 
2 canada  abc        urban      12        0.118 
3 canada  abc        total      22        0.121 
4 canada  xyz        rural       6        0.075 
5 canada  xyc        urban       7        0.0686
6 canada  xyc        total      13        0.0714
7 canada  population rural      80        1     
8 canada  population urban     102        1     
9 canada  population total     182        1
```